# Matlab: how to calculate the definite integral of a function over multiple limits?

Tags: matlab, limit, numerical-integration

Assume:

```
z = [0.4 0.5 0.75]'  
function y = myfunct(x)  
y = quad(@sin, 0, x)
```

I'd like to calculate the definite integral of sin(x) from 0 to 0.4, to 0.5, and 0.75, using:

```
myfunct(z)
```

However, Matlab returns:

```
??? Error using ==> quad at 70  
The limits of integration must be scalars.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also use `quadv` to do this.  BUT, instead of making a vector of integration limits,  make an array valued function so that when you integrate each element, the range of integration will be 0 to 1.

To be more specific, you want to integrate sin(x) from x = 0 to z.  This is the same as integrating sin(u z)*z from u = 0 to 1 (u-substitution).  Make an array function

```
F = @(u) [sin( .4 * u) * .4, sin( .5 * u ) * .5, sin( .75 * u ) * .75 ];
```

Then do

```
quadv(F,0,1)
```

Comment: I guess your way might be a bit faster than mine. But I'd restructure it a bit since you are repeating some information (i.e. when you want to change 1 limit, you have to change 2 numbers, when you want to change the function, you have to change 3 identifiers). The following code is equivalent to yours: `lims = [0.4 0.5 0.75]'; F = @(u)(sin(u.*lims).*lims);  quadv(F,0,1)`

Comment: agreed. that is a much cleaner way of doing it, and generalizes better.  I guess I was trying to be too explicit.

Comment: Thank you both for the helpful comments.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `arrayfun` function in recent versions of MATLAB:

```
z = [0.4 0.5 0.75]';
y = arrayfun(@(upperLim)(quad(@sin,0,upperLim)),z);
```